# How to access id_token in MSGraph SDK on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using [MSGraph SDK iOS](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ios) to login users with their Office365 accounts.

My end goal is to get:

- refresh token
- user details
- id token (`id_token` as described in [Azure Active Directory (AAD) endpoint documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#successful-response-1))

Using sample app I was able to login user, get a refresh token and user details (via `[[[[MSGraphClient client] me] request] getWithCompletion:...]`) but I can't find `id_token` anywhere.

Also, the Android version of the app I'm working on is using `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0` as a base URL for SDK and I'm trying to change it also in iOS app from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/`.

I might be missing something obvious or important in docs or sample app, sorry if that's the case.

**Question is:** how to get `id_token` in `MSGraphSDK` on iOS?

**UPD:**

Here's code I'm using:

```
[NXOAuth2AuthenticationProvider setClientId:<clientId> scopes:@[@"https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite", @"https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite", @"openid"]];
[[NXOAuth2AuthenticationProvider sharedAuthProvider] loginWithViewController:nil completion:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        return;
    }
    NSArray *accounts = [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] accountsWithAccountType:@"MSGraph"];
    NXOAuth2Account *account = accounts.firstObject;
}];
```

`NXOAuth2Account` doesn't have any property that can be connected with `id_token`. The question is how to get `id_token` from `NXOAuth2Client` or `MSGraphSDK` frameworks?

Comment: HI @derpoliuk , i want to create outlook calendar event using this iOS sdk. Could you please help me find a proper example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [`id_token`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens#id-tokens) is only returned if you're using the [OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc) flow. To enable this, you need to add `openid` to the list of scopes you're requesting and `id_token+code` as your `response-type`.

Optionally you can also request `email` and `profile` if you want to get a more "complete" `id_token`.

One additional item to keep in mind, the tokens are not provided by the SDK. They are obtained from Azure Active Directory via OAuth. The SDK simply takes the token you've previously obtained.

You can obtain a token using just about any library that supports OAuth 2.0 but I suspect the sample you're looking at is using [`NXOAuth2AuthenticationProvider`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ios-nxoauth2-adapter). Something along the lines of:

```
[NXOAuth2AuthenticationProvider setClientId:<clientId>
    scopes:@[@"https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite",
    @"https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite"]];
```

In order to obtain the `id_token` using the above example, you add the `openid` scope:

```
[NXOAuth2AuthenticationProvider setClientId:<clientId>
    scopes:@[@"https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite",
    @"https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite",
    @"openid"]];
```

Comment: Thank you for very detailed reply! I'll check it this week and will get back to you (or mark your answer as accepted)

Comment: I tried changing scopes but it didn't help because I can't get `id_token` from `MSGraphSDK` even if it's there. I did update my question with code I'm using.

Comment: I figured out how to get `id_token` from response. Will write answer later.

Comment: To keep things updated: `id_token` can be found in `NXOAuth2Account.accessToken.responseBody`. Example of parsing it can be found in `NXOAuth2AccessToken.m`

Comment: HI @Marc LaFleur , i want to create outlook calendar event using this iOS sdk. Could you please help me find a proper example.